# Why the incremental crawl is not running on schedule

Tags: 2013, search, administration, crawling, timer-service

I am working on a sharepoint farm 2013 on-premises. and i am facing a problem that my incremental crawl is not running on the schdule.

- I have a single search service:-

[image]

- and i define the search to run each 10 minutes starting from 00:00. so it should run @ 11:00, 11:10, 11:20 .. etc, as follow:-

[image]

but the problem is that the incremental crawl is running on time @ 11:05 ,11:15, 11:25 etc as follow:-

[image]

and when the incremental crawl correct time is met, nothing will run, and the above "next incremental crawl" time will be updated only.

I have a feeling that i have 2 search services running in a way or another, not sure what could be the problem.. also when i run the below command to do a farm back, after stopping the search:-

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication -Identity "Search Service Application"
Suspend-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication -Identity $ssa
Backup-SPFarm -Directory  \\****fileserv111\FarmBackUp\ -BackupMethod full -BackupThreads 10 -Force
```

i got this error on the backup:-

```
17/10/2018 20:45:20] FatalError: Backup failed for Object Crawl-0 (C: on ourservername) failed in event OnBackupComplete. For more information, see the spbackup.log or sprestore.log file located in the backup directory
```

so seems there are 2 search jobs running in a way or another... can anyone adivce n this please?

now i try to stop the timer job and clear the cache folder. also i tried to do IIS reset and also restart the search service. but nothing is able to fix this problem..

**Edit**
when the crawl correct time is met i can see the following errors inside the logs:-

```
10/18/2018 17:30:04.10  mssearch.exe (0x25C4)                       0x2AA0  SharePoint Server Search        Crawler:Content Plugin          ajjig   Medium      CSSFeeder::ReportPingSession: the session 8364aea5-5fe5-4285-ae5f-815f801140b1 has been pinged by PollCallbacks  
10/18/2018 17:30:04.15  w3wp.exe (0x3824)                           0x23E4  SharePoint Server               Database                        ahjqp   High        [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 10/18/2018 17:30:04.13, Original Level: Verbose] SQL connection time: 0.0353 for Data Source=****db\***db;Initial Catalog=Search_Service_Application_DB_37e******d;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15 00a3999e-66d7-60c4-bcfc-52edc852cc70
10/18/2018 17:30:04.15  w3wp.exe (0x3824)                           0x23E4  SharePoint Server               Database                        8acb    High        [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: VerboseEx] Reverting to process identity    00a3999e-66d7-60c4-bcfc-52edc852cc70
10/18/2018 17:30:07.05  w3wp.exe (0x3824)                           0x2974  SharePoint Server Search        Administration                  dn2l    High        SearchAppSystemWebPart: Query logging - 00:00:00.   00a3999e-66d7-60c4-bcfc-5db2a5c38b88
10/18/2018 17:30:07.05  w3wp.exe (0x3824)                           0x2974  SharePoint Server Search        Administration                  ahvvv   High        SearchAppSystemWebPart: Search Center URL - 00:00:00.   00a3999e-66d7-60c4-bcfc-5db2a5c38b88
10/18/2018 17:30:07.05  w3wp.exe (0x3824)                           0x2974  SharePoint Server Search        Administration                  dn2m    High        SearchAppSystemWebPart: Total - 00:00:03.   00a3999e-66d7-60c4-bcfc-5db2a5c38b88
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be a problem of owsTimer.exe . 
Did you try killing the owsTimer.exe processes from task manager and restarting the search services ?

**Do these steps :-**
     Go to the Server where you hosted your search service.

```
 Go to services.msc and stop the "SharePoint Timer Job"

 Open task manager and kill all the owsTimer.exe processes.

 Restart the SharePoint tier job. Click properties and set its start up type 
 to Automatic.

 Crawls should start working as per schedule.

 Let me know if this didnt help.
```

Comment: but inside our sharepoint server 2013, i can not find a process named `owsTimer.exe`, in my case i have a single process named `SPtimerV4.exe` and from its description it is saying that this process is for sharepoint timer service... so is this the one you are talking about ?

Comment: Yes that's the service  "SPtimerv4.exe "!!!. Go ahead and kill its process. If yoy look at it , it must be comsuming a very high memory .

Comment: just to make sure we are understanding each other.. now inside the Task Manage the "SPtimerv4.exe" appears under the "Services" tab  and not under the "Processes" tab.. so i can not tell how much memory it is consuming.. i also if i right click on the "SPtimerv4.exe" and i click on "go to process", then the "Processes" tab will open but no process is selected...i tried this on another SP-2013 and i can see the same behavior..

Comment: ..also if i stop the "SPtimerv4.exe" from Task Manager >> Services .. it is the same as go to services.msc and stop the "SharePoint Timer Job"

Comment: Yes it is the same . So after killing the processes from task manager , you need to go to services.msc and restart it from there ...however make sure the start up type is "Automatic".

Comment: as i told you before inside task manager i do not have any process running related to sharepoint timer job

Comment: Sounds like something is wrong . You are checking on the server where you hosted Search Service right ? There should be a process called SharePoint timer service in the task manager there. If still there is a problem , please just restart the SharePoint timer service from Services.msc .

Comment: i am saying there is not a Process for SP timer. inside task manager i have a service named SPtimerv4.exe" ... now i already restarted this service many times but did not fix the problem

Comment: Okay ...can you do this .....Can you go ahead and check in the crawl logs if anything has gone wrong . Are there any errors in the crawl logs ? Is anything failing while getting crawled ?

Comment: i edited my question with the logs